# Get multerS3 key from controller

Tags: express, amazon-s3, multer

I am using multer to store files in Amazon S3. I need to get the file's multerS3 key from my controller module for later access. My routes module:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var post_controller = require('../controllers/postController')
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var multer = require('multer');
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const s3 = new aws.S3();
const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'compressor-input',
    metadata: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, mongoose.Types.ObjectId())
    }
  })
});

router.post('/:id/upload', upload.array('item_images', 12), post_controller.images_upload);
```

Answer (score 0):

MulterS3 doesn't expose any file specific parameters. You should instead use S3.putObject() in your controller and generate keys either in middleware passed to the router.post function or in your controller module. Express-fileupload is useful when using S3.putObject() because it exposes files in the express request object like so: `req.files`.

Answer (score 0):

req.files will contain all the information about the uploaded file returned by Amazon.

```
app.post('/upload', upload.array('photos', 3), function(req, res, next) {
  
  console.log(req.files)
  
  res.send('Successfully uploaded ' + req.files.length + ' files!')
})
```